# How to write to the beginning of a file when using Python subprocess.call()?

Tags: python, file-io

I run the following script:

```py
with open("logfile.txt", 'w') as log_file:
    cmd = path + '/somebinary'
    log_file.write("Running the command: %s\n" % cmd)
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True, stdout=log_file, stderr=log_file)
```

However, the `cmd` variable gets written to the end of the file and not to the beginning (which I was expecting / hoping for). Can somebody explain to me why and how to prevent this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The operating system performs buffering which can cause output to occur in unexpected order. To force it, `flush` the file handle after writing.

```
with open("logfile.txt", 'w') as log_file:
    cmd = path + '/somebinary'
    log_file.write("Running the command: %s\n" % cmd)
    log_file.flush()
    subprocess.call(cmd, shell=True, stdout=log_file, stderr=log_file)
```

Demo: https://ideone.com/U8RPBy

As an aside, you [generally want to avoid `shell=True`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess); try

```
    cmd = [path + '/somebinary']
    ...
    subprocess.call(cmd, stdout=log_file, stderr=log_file)
```

and perhaps make sure your `PATH` is correct instead of hardcoding a specific `path`.

Comment: Thank you so much! For some reason the my script will not work without `shell=True`. I will have to investigate. And I am not sure why you suggest to put the path into a list.

Comment: The linked question about avoiding `shell=True` explains they why and the how of that. If you need a shell for some reason (like `somebinary` is not actually a binary at all) then of course that refactoring is not possible.